# PyQt5 & PySide2 / Could not load the Qt platform plugin "windows" in "" even though it was found

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, pyside2

Development environment

```
 1. Windows 10 / Python 3.6.8 / Pyinstaller 3.4 / PyQt5 5.10
 2. Windows 10 / Python 3.6.8 / Pyinstaller 3.4 / PySide2 5.11.0
 3. Windows 10 / Python 3.6.8 / Pyinstaller 3.4 / PyQt5 5.9.2
```

Execution environment

```
Windows Server 2008 SP2
```

In case 1, 2 : Below Error Occurred.

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "windows" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized.
Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: minimal, offscreen, webgl, windows.
```

But case 3 : No Error.

The results of testing the higher versions than Qt 5.10 are the same as case 1, 2.

I must use PySide2. but PySide2 does not have a lower version than Qt 5.9.2.

Is there a way to avoid the error using PySide2 ?

Comment: I recommend using fbs since the generation of the executable is very simple. https://github.com/mherrmann/fbs

Answer (score -1):

With Anaconda:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyside2
```

But is an older version. (v5.6)
With the older version, I did not encounter any problems so far. I have the same problem with the new version but I need it because the older does not have support for QtCharts